# How many sets of digits are there so each digit would belong to the corresponding set?

Tags: combinatorics

Given nine sets:

$X_1 \{2,3,9\}, X_2 \{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}, X_3 \{3, 9\}, X_4 \{1, 2, 3, 7, 9\}, X_5 \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9\}, X_6 \{2, 3, 6, 7\}, X_7 \{1, 6, 7, 9\} , X_8 \{1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9\}, X_9 \{2, 9\} $

How many sets of different digits $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, a_8, a_9 )$ are there so $a_i \in x_i $ ?

Have tried using combinatorical formules, seems like there are too many variants.

Comment: How many **sets**?  How many **multisets**?  Or how many ordered **n-tuples**?  If you are merely asking for the number of ordered $n$-tuples, this is a *direct* application of [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: It is how many sets. The problem is: for example, I choose number 2 from the first set and then choose another number from the second set. And I need to know whether I can use it in the 3rd set or not.

Comment: To emphasize, do you consider $(2,2,3,2,2,3,1,1,2)$ to be a valid outcome despite the fact that there are multiple two's appearing? (*would you have considered that to be simply the outcome $\{1,2,3\}$ instead, simplifying so that each appears only once?*)  (*If you did consider this outcome to be $\{1,2,3\}$, then how do you reverse this? which is $a_1$ in $\{2,3,8\}$?*)  If you allow repetition of digits do you consider it to be the same or different than $(2,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,2)$? (*the number of occurrences of each number is the same between the two examples, but the order has changed*)

Comment: No. Digits must be different.

Comment: Assuming the $a_i$ must be different, ie you can't choose $a_1$ and $a_2$ both equal 2, an approach is to consider only $X_1$, $X_3$ and $X_9$.  then using what you learn there consider $X_4$, $X_6$, and $X_7$.  Finally consider the last three $X$.  (Hint: I get an answer of 18).

Comment: If you really are interested in **ordered** sets like you seem to be saying... you can brute force this, or you can approach using algebraic graph theory.  Create yourself a bipartite graph on eighteen vertices with vertices $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_9,v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_9$ and adjacencies between $u_i$ and $v_j$ if $j\in X_i$.  You can then count the number of perfect matchings [using known techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs), each perfect matching corresponding to one such selection for a set.

Comment: If you are interested in **sets** then the only result is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ since this is considered to be the "*same*" set as $\{2,1,3,4,5,9,8,6,7\}$ or any other arrangement of the digits within the set.  Note that it doesn't matter in the set which of $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_9$ is actually the specific $a_i$ that is equal to $1$, just as it doesn't matter which of $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_9$ is actually the specific $a_i$ that is equal to $2$, etc... Terminology and being able to unambiguously convey what objects you wish to count is incredibly important for questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

Consider only $X_1$, $X_3$, and $X_9$.  $a_1$ can be 2, 3, or 9.  If $a_1=2$, then $a_9=9$ so $a_3=3$.  If $a_1=3$, then $a_3=9$ so $a_2=2$.  Finally if If $a_1=9$, then $a_3=3$ and $a_9=2$.

The possibilities for $(a_1, a_3, a_9)$ are $(2,3,9)$, $(3,9,2)$, or $(9,3,2)$.

Since 2, 3, 9 are "used up" you can repeat the process with $X_4$, $X_6$, and $X_7$.

The possibilities for $(a_4, a_6, a_7)$ are $(1,6,7)$, $(1,7,6)$, or $(7,6,1)$.

Now 1, 6, 7 are also "used up".  Last considering $X_2$, $X_5$, and $X_6$ gives the possibilities for $(a_2, a_5, a_8)$ are $(5,4,8)$ or $(8,5,4)$.

The total number is $3\times 3 \times 2 = 18$.